# struct perf_event_attr: setting exclude_kernel bit cause syscall error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, perf

Whenever I set `exclude_kernel` bit which is a member of `struct perf_event_attr`, I get an error `operation not supported` upon executing `syscall` function. This does not just happen with `exclude_kernel` bit but also when setting `exclude_user` and `exclude_hv`? The kernel I'm working with is custom `v4.6`. I'm able to use `perf` command line tool with no issues on this system. What could be the reason behind this error? How can I fix it?

Note: In case an example is needed, I have tested this issue with the same basic example provided in [`perf_event_open` man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html#EXAMPLE) and I have the same issue.

Another note: Regarding the way I have installed `perf tool`, I have compiled and installed it myself on the system

Comment: Have you checked `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` ?

Comment: I have set this value to -1

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of your error message - along with a sample of the code that you have written ? Are you able to run `perf record -e <event_name>` and subsequently do a `perf report` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to run `perf record` followed by `perf script` or `perf report`.
I get the error message, when the value of file descriptor == -1, the source code compiles successfully but upon execution I get error message `operation not supported`. As I have explained in the question, the source code is the same as the one in perf_event_open man pages...

Comment: Can you tell us what is the error number ? Is it `EACCES` or `EPERM` ? Also what architecture are you using ?

Comment: Architecture ARMv7, error number is 95 --> `operation not supported`
so it is either `ENOTSUP` or `EOPNOTSUP`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171483/discussion-between-arnabjyoti-kalita-and-user3527764).